# Regex get text inside one pair of square brackets

Tags: regex

In the text below how do I get the text inside the first pair of square brackets

`xxxx [I can be any text and even have digits like 0 25 ] [sdfsfsf] [ssf sf565wf]`

This is what I tried. But it goes till the last square bracket.

```
.*\[.*]
```

What i want selected is

```
[I can be any text and even have digits like 0 25 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go past the closing square bracket, use `[^\]]*` in place of `.*`:

```
^[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*])
```

Add `^` anchor at the beginning if you would like to search multiple lines.

Add a capturing group around the square brackets, and get the content of that group to obtain the text that you need.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pL1vT7/2)

Comment: I want just the text inside the first square brackets selected. I updated my post with the desired result. Sorry I wasn't clear the first time.

Comment: @developer747 You need to add a capturing group around the part of the text that you wish to capture (shown in green in the updated demo at the link).

Answer (score 1):

Another one with [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tO8iX2/2). A bit complicated though:

```
(\[[^\]]+\])[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\]].*\])
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
(\[[^\]]+\])            #capturing group
                        #match first [] pair

[^\[\]]*                #match characters except ] and [

(?:\[[^\]].*\])         #non-capturing group
                        #match all the rest [] pairs
                        #this is a greedy match
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` and `+` are 'greedy' by default, so they try to match as much text as possible. If you want them to match as little as possible, you can make them non-greedy with `?`, eg `.*\[.*?\]`. Also, the `.*` at the beginning matches any number of any characters before the opening square bracket, so this regex will match all text up to a ']' as long as there is a '[' somewhere before the ']'. If you only want to match the brackets and their contents, you want simply `\[.*?\]`.

Non-greedy modifiers with `?` are not supported in all regex engines; if it's available to you you should write it with `?` because it makes your intent clearer, but if you are using a simpler regex engine you can achieve the same effect by using `\[[^\]]*\]` instead. This is a negated character class, which matches as many as possible of any character except ']'.